# Jquery's ajax request fails in remote, not in local

Tags: url, jquery

I am using an ajax request which works in local, not in remote, because of an url problem. It looks like :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../classes/file_to_process.php",
        data: "my data"
        success: function(msg){...}
})
```

I keep on having an error message : `"The requested URL /classes/file_to_process.php {without the double dots behind it} was not found on this server"`

My working directory is in a folder /prod, in which there is the index.php. The /classes folder is at the same level as /prod. So to fetch it from an jquery request, I use ../classes/file_to_process

I tried an absolute path by using pwd to fetch the correct path on the remote server, but I have the same message

Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: try `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}` to see error

Comment: Check the request URL in the console to ensure that it's correct.

Comment: Maybe the file was really not found in the server. I see that in your code you call for "file_to_process.php" and the error message says "Campaign.php". Are you sure the name is correct? is this a typo?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for http://serverfault.com/ because it looks like a serverside issue.

Comment: **classes/file_to_process.php** have you tried this way.

Comment: Open it in Firefox and enable Firebug. Then go to the NET tab and see what is the URL that shows as 404 error.

Comment: No !! I mislead the url I mentionned earlier is not correct, because it shows www.siteurl.com/classes/file_to_process, but the classes folder is behind the inedx file, that's the reason why, I put ../classes/file_to_process

Comment: Maybe you have some htaccess in the remote server that doesn't allow you to send an ajax request to that file?

Comment: www.siteurl.com/../classes/file_to_process doesn't make sense for an Internet address. What is the absolute URL to the file you are trying to access (i.e. without '..')?

Comment: I tried with an absolute path on the remote server, but it didn't work. I am going to desactivate the .htaccess, maybe this causes the problem

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I tried to desactivate the .htaccess, but it didn't worked...

Comment: @HristoYankov, since the folder /classes is at the same level as the /public folder wich contains index.php. Is it possible I can't access this file ?

Comment: If the classes folder is at the same level as your 'public', then you can't access it (it is outside the 'public' folder, hence, not being served).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'classes' folder is on the same level as 'public', then you can't access it directly from the client (AJAX, JavaScript, etc). You need to either put it in the 'public' or map it to /classes virtual path. Or you can have a trusted .php file in your 'public' folder that accesses the 'classes' on the server side.

TL;DR;
From the client side you cannot access a file that is not being served to the client.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. Finally, I adjusted the url and changed the routing and put the file_to_process code in an other file